# What does "subsampling at 5%" mean?

Tags: subsampling

This from the description of a [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/amex-default-prediction/data):

> Note that the negative class has been subsampled for this dataset at 5%, and thus receives a 20x weighting in the scoring metric.

They don't mention the metric used – I am guessing its accuracy, since it's a classification problem. But I don't understand the subsampling bit. In the training dataset provided, the 'negative' class comprises almost 25%. Are they saying in the 'population'/their database, it's 5%?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! [Note that they are likely doing this to fix a problem that proper statistical methods do not see as a problem.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274)

Comment: Your guess about using accuracy is wrong. "The evaluation metric, , for this competition is the mean of two measures of rank ordering: Normalized Gini Coefficient, , and default rate captured at 4%, ." https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/amex-default-prediction/overview/evaluation

Comment: The negative class is about 75% of the datase, not 25% as the question states. The actual numbers are 118,828 positive cases and 340,085 negative cases.

Comment: @dipetkov missed that, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Okay, so I guess negative class means 0 (not defaulting) and that's 75%. I am still confused about the subsampling bit though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The note means that only 5%, or 1 in 20, of the negative transactions are presented, whereas the positive transactions are represented in full.

If the negative data weren't subsampled, there would be 25 times as many negative transactions, or about 8.5 million. We can conclude that the positive ratio (positive meaning a default on credit card payment) in the full data is about 1.6%.